# Calculate the unit gradient vector

Tags: image-processing

I have a problem to calculate the unit gradient vector. I have a formula but i didn't understand. If possible, would you be able to explain this formula in more detail. I must implement an image for eye center localization. Thank you for your interest.
[UGVs formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKpFB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Gradient vector calculation will give you the magnitude and orientation for each pixel in the image. This means you need to calculate the derivatives along the x-axis and y-axis separately. Then fuse them to calculate magnitude and direction of vectors. If you are using OpenCV or MATLAB, you will see functions to calculate gradient magnitude and direction of pixels in an image. For example for MATLAB, see imgradient amd imgradientxy functions.